# The top cohomology group for non-orientable space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For any compact connected $d$-dimensional space, the top cohomology group $H^d(M^d,Z) = Z$, if the space is orientable.
My question is that what is the top cohomology group, if the space is non-orientable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $M^d$ is compact and not orientable, then $H^d(M^d,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. You can compute this using the universal coefficient theorem together with the fact that $H_{d-1}(M^d)$ must be a direct sum of a free abelian group and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. All those things can be seen in Bredon, in the section named "The Orientation Bundle".

Comment: Do you mean $H_{d-1}(M^d,Z)$ must be free, instead of $H_{n-1}(M^d)$ must be free? Also $H_3(RP^4,Z)=Z_2$ which is not free.

Comment: Yes, I mean $H_{d-1}$. And sorry, the argument of $H_{d-1}$ being free is for the orientable case to show that $H^d$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$. I'll fix the answer.